# Show by induction that a function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, induction

My question is about the proof of the corollary 3.3 page 21 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504221).

Let $(E,d,\mu)$ be a measured metric space with $\mu$ doubling.
We write $\mathcal{M}$ the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator.
Let $1<q\leq\infty$ and $a>1$ be fixed.
Let $F,G\in L^1_{loc}(E)$ be non-negative.

> **Definition** : We says $(F,G)\in\mathcal{E}_{q,a}$ if for every ball $B$ we can find
> non-negative measurable functions $G_B, H_B$ defined on $B$ with $$ F
>  \leq G_B + H_B ~ \text{a.e. on}\, B $$ such that $$ \begin{split}
>  \left( \frac{1}{\mu(B)}\int_B (H_B)^q\, d\mu \right)^{1/q} &\leq a
>  \inf_{x\in B} \mathcal{M} F(x) + \inf_{x\in B} G(x), \\
>  \frac{1}{\mu(B)}\int_B G_B\, d\mu &\leq \inf_{x\in B} G(x).
>  \end{split} $$

Let $1<\rho$ and let $F,G\in\mathcal{E}_{q,a}$ such that $\|F\|_1<\infty$ and $\|G\|_\rho<\infty$.
In this proof we define a function
$$
\Phi(t) = \rho\int_0^t \lambda^{\rho-1}\mu\{\mathcal{M}F>\lambda\}\,d\lambda
$$
for $t\geq 0$.
Also after using a precedent proposition we show the innequality
$$
\Phi(Kt) \leq
\frac{1}{2} \Phi(t) + \left( \frac{K}{\gamma} \right)^\rho \lVert G \rVert_\rho^\rho
$$
where $K$ and $\gamma\leq 1$ are some constants.
And then the author says that "An easy iteration shows that $\Phi$ is bounded".
I don't see what kind of iteration we have to do.

Comment: I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration that the paper is referring to is that you can apply the inequality iteratively. You can start with $\Phi(K^n t)$ and apply the inequality over and over until you get to $\Phi(t)$, and the form of the inequality makes it so that this is bounded even as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Since $K^nt$ gets as big as you want, this gives boundedness. A more precise answer is below.

---

To make the inequality simpler, we can just take $C$ to be a constant and say that $\Phi(Kt) \leq \tfrac{1}{2} \Phi(t) + C$ for any $t \geq 0$. Now, consider the sequence $\Phi(1), \Phi(K), \Phi(K^2)$, etc. You can approximate $\Phi(K^2)$ by applying the inequality twice:
$$
\Phi(K^2) \leq \tfrac{1}{2}\Phi(K) + C
\leq \tfrac{1}{2} (\tfrac{1}{2} \Phi(1) + C) + C
= \tfrac{1}{4} \Phi(1) + \tfrac{3}{2}C
$$
By continuing like this, you can approximate each $\Phi(K^n)$.
By iteration on $n$, you can show that
$$
\Phi(K^n) \leq \tfrac{1}{2^n} \Phi(1) + C(2-\tfrac{1}{2^n}).
$$
Approximating more loosely, we have $\Phi(K^n) \leq \Phi(1) + 2C$ for each $n$. Since presumably $K>1$ (the paper says we can choose $K$ "large enough"), and since $\Phi$ is increasing (if I understand correctly), this is enough to conclude that $\Phi$ is bounded. (If I've misunderstood and $\Phi$ is not increasing, it is also enough to show that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \Phi(t)$ exists.)